# Add count of record in crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports-2005

i am working with Microsoft visual studio 2005, i want to add total record count as well as record count as per group defined in report.

Say my group name field is `Group1`.  i want record count for this group as well as total record count.

I am new to this.. appropriate your help.

Comment: you want serial number or total number of records or sum of selected record?

Comment: I want total number of record in that group

Answer (score 0):

crystal report has some special fields,For serial number in crystal report=>right_click=>Insert=>special fields=>record number,incase you want serial number groupwise include record number inside groupby section.

Comment: use it http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/798-add-group-count-crystal-report---using-summary.aspx